# Example of ODE $x' = f(x)$ for $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that solution is bounded but not periodic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

On the last page of these notes:

http://www.cds.caltech.edu/archive/help/uploads/wiki/files/179/lecture5Bs.pdf

the author says that "for $n \geq 3$ trajectories may wander around a bounded region without settle down to a fixed point or a closed orbit."  I've been trying to think of an IVP in which this scenario happens but can't come up with anything.  Is there some classic example someone can point me to?

More specifically, could you give me an example of an ODE $x' = f(x)$ for some $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that a solution is bounded but is neither an equilibrium nor a periodic orbit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case $n>2$ the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem doesn's hold and the system can be chaotic (it can have strange attractors). A classic example you can easily find is the Lorenz system. It present, for the proper values of the parameters, the famous butterfly-like attractor.